# Packing an android library on a JAR that uses JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java

I have an Android java library that uses some native code. I have added this java library to a client project.

May I have to add script that copy the native library to libs folder on my client project? Or this native library is included inside the java library's jar?

If you need more details or if you don't understand anything, tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you need support any longer.
You don't need any scripts when you added the Android library project to your Android project.
I have a similar configuration and it works fine.

For more information how to use the JNI, you can look here: [Issues with SHA1 hash implementation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350657/issues-with-sha1-hash-implementation-in-android/6363465#6363465)

Answer (score 1):

You should move .so files(libs, obj etc.) from your project(that will be JAR library) to main project(that will use your JAR library).
After that, make *.JAR again and attach *.JAR to your main project. I solved this problem in this way. :) I hope my answer will be helpful. bye, VansFannel!