# How do I run a sample android ndk program in eclipse?

Tags: android-ndk

I have created a sample android NDK program in eclipse. I'm working with Windows XP, I know that there are some issues regarding NDK in eclipse,but i installed the cygwin tool for this..
Is this enough for running ndk???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need GNU Make, which you can install with cygwin.
After that you can switch in cygwin to your project and run there **ndk-build**.

For more details have a look on my tutorial:
[Issues with SHA1 hash implementation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350657/issues-with-sha1-hash-implementation-in-android/6363465#6363465)
There is a section about building.