# Calculating MD5 Hash (RFC 1321 conform) in Matlab via Java

Tags: java, matlab, hash, md5, rfc

I want to calculate MD5 (or other) file hashes ([RFC 1321](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt) conform) within MATLAB using the Java-Security-Implementations. Thus I coded

```
mddigest=java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5');
filestream=java.io.FileInputStream(java.io.File(filename));
digestream=java.security.DigestInputStream(filestream,mddigest);
md5hash=reshape(dec2hex(typecast(mddigest.digest,'uint8')),1,[])
```

and the routine is working fine. Somehow, the result differs from given tools.
Maybe there are problems with the file-encoding? Should't MATLAB solve that internally?
I'd like to reproduce the results, one gets by md5sum (on linux), which equal those from HashCalc (Windows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is two problems:

1. You don't read the file.
2. You have to transpose the matrix
   before reshape it.

This code works:

```
mddigest   = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5'); 
filestream = java.io.FileInputStream(java.io.File(filename)); 
digestream = java.security.DigestInputStream(filestream,mddigest);

while(digestream.read() ~= -1) end

md5hash=reshape(dec2hex(typecast(mddigest.digest(),'uint8'))',1,[]);
```

**/!\** Edit : [p.vitzliputzli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260721/p-vitzliputzli) answered a [very much faster solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483925/1753493) which should be used instead of this one.

Comment: Haven't you missed a couple of news?

Comment: Hi @TobiasRitzau and Stéphane Pinchaux, I'm very sorry, that it took such a long time. Yout code works fine - thanks. Merry christmas.

Comment: i get Undefined variable "algorithm" or class "algorithm.digest". Is there a prefix before algorithm.digest that i need to add? Or should it be "mddigest.digest" instead of "algorithm.digest"?

Comment: @Eagle: Yes, it should be mddigest instead of algorithm. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Stephane's solution works but is quite slow due to MATLAB's limitation of not being able to supply a JAVA byte[] array to the read method of the DigestInputStream (or any other InputStream).

However, we can adapt Thomas Pornin's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350731/1260721) (discarding the FileInputStream) in order to arrive at:

```
mddigest   = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5'); 

bufsize = 8192;

fid = fopen(filename);

while ~feof(fid)
    [currData,len] = fread(fid, bufsize, '*uint8');       
    if ~isempty(currData)
        mddigest.update(currData, 0, len);
    end
end

fclose(fid);

hash = reshape(dec2hex(typecast(mddigest.digest(),'uint8'))',1,[]);
```

This solution takes about 0.018s to compute the hash of a 713kB file whereas the other solution takes about 31s.

Answer (score 2):

You never [read from the `DigestInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/DigestInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

This means no bytes will be digested.

You must read the entire file (via the `DigestInputStream`) and *then* call `digest` to get the digest value.

Comment: Oh, thanks Joachim - this is needed. But further, as I noted down, I'd like to build file-hasher conform to RFC1321, thus with a one bit and further zero padding and after that adding 64 Bit length.   Is there a way to get that into the stream by hand?